# Failed to deploy jhipster-registry with openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, jhipster, docker-image

I'm working with microservices apps using jhipster in openshift.
i tried to deploy with existing jhipster-registry docker image and pulling from github repository.

When i deploy the image resulting this errors  :

```
2017-09-18 08:16:24.233 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for [/target/jhipster-registry.log]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(target/jhipster-registry.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: target/jhipster-registry.log (No such file or directory)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at io.github.jhipster.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp.main(JHipsterRegistryApp.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
```

can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your docker image is unable to find a given file or directory. According to [jhipster's github page](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/pull/13), if you want to dockerize your application, you should run it as `mvn package docker:build`. This will generate a docker image, that you can then push to the internal OpenShift registry, and then deploy that image from OpenShift.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the [issue with jhipster-registry Docker image](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/issues/189)

I am using jhipster-registry:v4.0.4 in OpenShift and that works.